# Mapping php array to nested json

Tags: php, json

I have been searching all over SO for a hint and there are some q&a looking somewhat like this, but no luck so far.
I am basically trying to get this php array:

```
array (size=xx)
  14 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '14' (length=2)
      1 => float 80
  15 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '15' (length=2)
      1 => float 70
  1522 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '15' (length=2)
      1 => float 70
      2 => string '22' (length=2)
      3 => float 60
  1523 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '15' (length=2)
      1 => float 70
      2 => string '23' (length=2)
      3 => float 70
  152329 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string '15' (length=2)
      1 => float 70
      2 => string '23' (length=2)
      3 => float 70
      4 => string '29' (length=2)
      5 => float 30
  152334 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string '15' (length=2)
      1 => float 70
      2 => string '23' (length=2)
      3 => float 70
      4 => string '34' (length=2)
      5 => float 80
  16 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '16' (length=2)
      1 => float 30
  1624 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '16' (length=2)
      1 => float 30
      2 => string '24' (length=2)
      3 => float 35
```

**transformed (or mapped?) into this json:**

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "14",
            "name": "Id 14",
            "value": "80.0",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "15",
            "name": "ID 15",
            "value": "70.0",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "22",
                    "name": "ID 22",
                    "score": "60.0",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "id": "23",
                    "name": "Id 23",
                    "score": "70.0",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "29",
                            "name": "ID 29",
                            "score": "30.0",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "34",
                            "name": "Id 34",
                            "score": "80.0",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "16",
            "name": "ID 16",
            "score": "30.0",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "24",
                    "name": "ID 24",
                    "score": "35.0",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to use the php map() function, but I am not able to do the transition correctly.
So please, could you post a snippet or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. I'm assuming your current array is called `$oldArray`

```
// will use this later
function reindex($array) {
    if (!empty($array['children'])) {
        $array['children'] = array_values($array['children']);
        foreach ($array['children'] as $key => $value) {
            $array['children'][$key] = reindex($value);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

$newArray = array(
    'children' => array()
);

// refactor array into something more suitable
foreach ($oldArray as $oldArrayKey => $oldArrayValues) {

    $count = count($oldArrayValues);
    $currentArray = &$newArray['children'];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i = $i + 2) {

        $id = $oldArrayValues[$i];
        $value = $oldArrayValues[$i + 1];

        if (!isset($currentArray[$id])) {
            $currentArray[$id] = array(
                'id' => $id,
                'name' => 'ID ' . $id,
                'value' => $value,
                'children' => array()
            );
        }

        $currentArray = &$currentArray[$id]['children'];
    }
}

// reindex the children, or json_encode will treat ['children'] as an object instead of an array
$newArray = reindex($newArray);

echo json_encode($newArray);
```

Let me know if you need an explanation for any part...

Comment: Thanks, that was fast - and pretty close!
I am, however, somehow missing the "[" after "children:" and "]" finishing them. Just like the empty children correctly does.
Do you think that's possible?

Comment: Also i noticed on some you have "value" and others you have "score", I couldn't work out the logic behind that so they are all just "value" right now. If there is a pattern, let me know... might just be a typo though

Comment: Sorry about the "score", it was a typo on my side. But thank you - it now works perfectly!